# Component version in urancode udeploy

Tags: urbancode

On my project , I have to 2 create 2 drop-down list-one for available snapshot and other one is for versions of compoments associated with the app. basically I used rest api to grab all components associated with application, n pass each component to get the versions. The problem is I'm having difficulty passing the component(most app has more than 1 components). What is the recommended way to do it. I tried and it gave me error: Cannot convert object of type \u0027 to type \ u0027 system.collections.Generic.Idictionary'..

Comment: Which API command is giving you that error?

Comment: I think its not the API, but the parameter that i  pass into another ajax request. Basically I have 2 ajax request. One by passing App Name to get the components name and again passing that component name into another ajax request to get versions. When i passed the components name, it is throwing above error. I tried  to loop through each components and get their available versions but its throwing above error. How do i pass list of components as a data for ajax request?

Comment: i found the issue and has been resolved. Thank you for your quick response.